Rails/Ruby join using calculated field
I'm trying to work out if/how I can use a field from a joined table in a calculation inside a where statement.
Plot.joins(:developer)
    .where('plots.reservation_release_date < ?',developer.auto_complete.months.ago)

Each developer has an integer auto_complete value.  I don't know arel very well and cannot think of how to approach this.  Any help appreciated

RECOMMENDED SOLUTION
You could always just use raw SQL like: (assuming postresql)
"plots.reservation_release_date < NOW() - interval '1 month' * developers.auto_complete"

There is no risk to using this since there is no user input. Given that SQL date math is ugly and inherently different between flavors of SQL (see below) the lack of portability will exist regardless, so for the sake of readability this would be my preferred implementation.
AREL
Since you mentioned and tagged one of my favorite tags (arel), I will provide some options for that as well.
The Arel for comparison is fairly simple
Plot.arel_table[:reservation_release_date].lt(VALUE)

The complexity comes in with the fact that you need functions and mathematical operations (based on developer.auto_complete.months.ago) to assemble the desired query.
Since you are looking to subtract the developer.auto_complete (assumed to be an integer representing number of months) value from the current date we will need to convert that to SQL.
For Example:
POSTGRESQL
condition = Arel::Nodes::Subtraction.new(
              Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('NOW',[]), # NamedFunctions don't include Math 
              Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
                'interval', Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('1 month')
              ) * Developer.arel_table[:auto_complete]
)
Plot.joins(:developer).where(Plot.arel_table[:reservation_release_date].lt(condition))

SQL:
plots.reservation_release_date < NOW() - interval '1 month' * developers.auto_complete

UPDATED: Based on @max's comment there are alternate means on computation resulting in the same logical operation including:
condition = Arel::Nodes::Subtraction.new(
             Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('NOW',[]), # NamedFunctions don't include Math 
             Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('make_interval',
               [Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('=>',
                  Arel.sql('months'),
                  Developer.arel_table[:auto_complete])
               ])
)

resulting in:
plots.reservation_release_date < NOW() - make_interval(months => developers.auto_complete)

As of PostgreSQL 16 you can use:
condition = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_subtract',[
              Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('NOW',[]),
              Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('make_interval',
               [Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('=>',
                  Arel.sql('months'),
                  Developer.arel_table[:auto_complete])
               ])]
)


resulting in
plots.reservation_release_date < date_subtract(NOW(), make_interval(months => developers.auto_complete))

MSSQL
condition = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
             'DATEADD',
             [Arel.sql('m'),
              Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new('-',Developer.arel_table[:auto_complete]),
              Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('GETDATE',[])])
Plot.joins(:developer).where(Plot.arel_table[:reservation_release_date].lt(condition))

SQL:
plots.reservation_release_date < DATEADD(m,- developers.auto_complete,GETDATE())

MYSQL
Syntax is ugly could substitute some raw SQL
condition = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE_ADD',[
              Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('NOW',[]), 
              Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
                'INTERVAL',  
                Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
                   Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new('-', Developer.arel_table[:auto_complete]), 
                   Arel.sql('MONTH')
                )
              )] 
)
Plot.joins(:developer).where(Plot.arel_table[:reservation_release_date].lt(condition))

SQL:
plots.reservation_release_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - developers.auto_complete MONTH)


I think you can simplify this quite a bit (at least in Arel) by using the age and make_interval functions instead of unitary operators. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Thanks for your comprehensive aswer.  I appreciate that.  I'll try the postgres arel and see how I go

@engineersmnky exactly.
